# Google cloud storgae - Bucket list error: 403 Forbidden

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I'm trying to get the list of Buckets in my Google cloud project using the service account.

Here is the program:

```
package com.mypackage.api;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.services.storage.Storage;
import com.google.api.services.storage.StorageScopes;
import com.google.api.services.storage.model.Bucket;

public class TestClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        String project = "my-project";

        Storage storage = createStorageService();
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        List<Bucket> buckets = storage.buckets().list(project).execute().getItems();
        if(buckets != null) {
            for(Bucket b : buckets) {
                list.add(b.getName());
            }
        }


    }

    public static Storage createStorageService() throws IOException, GeneralSecurityException {
        HttpTransport httpTransport = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
        JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();


        GoogleCredential credential = GoogleCredential.getApplicationDefault();
        if (credential.createScopedRequired()) {
            credential = credential.createScoped(Arrays.asList(StorageScopes.DEVSTORAGE_FULL_CONTROL, "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"));
        }

        return new Storage.Builder(httpTransport, jsonFactory,
                 credential).setApplicationName("My Application")
                 .build();

    }
}
```

And I got the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "mytool@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 333XXXXX67.",
    "reason" : "forbidden"
  } ],
  "message" : "mytool@my-project.iam.gserviceaccount.com does not have storage.buckets.list access to project 333XXXXX67."
}
```

I have added "Owner" scope to my service account. But still I'm getting permission denied error.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check your credential. Are you sure that credential.createScopedRequired() is true, and credentional get required scopes for read info? For example https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.read_only. Such an answer (403) means that you do not have permission.

Answer (score 0):

I rectified this error by changing the credentials type file. Initially, i took web application file so that's why I got this error. Thank you for responding to my question.